# Is FSharp.Data.DesignTime .NET 4.5 only?

Tags: f#, f#-data

I'm using FSharp.Data.1.1.10 in a .NET 4.0 project, and when I add FSharp.Data with Nuget, it creates a **packages\FSharp.Data.1.1.10\lib\net40** directory where it puts **FSharp.Data.dll** and **FSharp.Data.DesignTime.dll**. According to Telerik JustDecompile, **FSharp.Data.dll** is a .NET 4.0 dll, but **FSharp.Data.DesignTime.dll** is a .NET 4.5 dll even though it resides in the net40 subdirectory.

So, is FSharp.Data.DesignTime .NET 4.5 only, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, FSharp.Data.DesignTime is .NET 4.5, but that doesn't mean your projects have to be .NET 4.5 also, it's just a design time component, and you shouldn't even reference it, only FSharp.Data.dll

EDIT:

In FSharp.Data 1.1.x the DesignTime dll was being added by mistake when referencing the nuget package, in 2.x that is now fixed

Comment: So, I'll just remove the reference manually and live happily ever after. :-)