# Can't build an F# project using the ApiaryTypeProvider. FSharp.Data.DesignTime can not be found

Tags: f#, type-providers, apiary

I have an F# Library Project ( Not Portable Library ) with the following code:

```
   let db = new ApiaryProvider<"themoviedb">("http://api.themoviedb.org")
   db.AddQueryParam("api_key", TmdbApiKey)
   let test = 
      let movie = db.Movie.GetMovie("550")
      let creds = movie.Credits()
      creds
```

Unfortunately when I try to build this I get the error:

```
C:\Users\Andy\Documents\Programming\Projects\MovieMediaManager\MovieMediaManagerLib\
Library1.fs(73,19):

error FS3033: The type provider 'ApiaryProvider.ProviderImplementation.ApiaryProvider'
reported an error in the context of provided type
'ApiaryProvider.ApiaryProvider,ApiName="themoviedb"+Movie3', member 'Credits'.

The error: Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Data.DesignTime, Version=2.0.7.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find
the file specified.
```

On the line:

```
let credits = movie.Credits()
```

I'm using the ApiaryProvider 1.0.1.
The FSharp.Data.DesignTime dlls are in the nuget packages file in this directory:

```
\packages\ApiaryProvider.1.0.1\lib\net40
```

I read on this question here:
[Is FSharp.Data.DesignTime .NET 4.5 only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214044/is-fsharp-data-designtime-net-4-5-only)

That you can remove the reference and it should work but this mentions FSharp.Data and that it should be fixed in the new nuget packages.

Am I doing something wrong?
Do I need to checkout the source code and manually remove the reference and rebuild?

Comment: Can you try copying all files from the `lib/net40` directory of the `FSharp.Data` package to the directory where `ApiaryProvider.dll` is?

Comment: Hi Tomas.  Thanks for the response.  I've copied all the files from FSharp.Data.2.0.7/lib/net40 to Apiary.1.0.1 /lib/net40.  Now when I build I get the error: 
parse error FS3053: error : The type provider constructor has thrown an exception: API restriction: The assembly 'file:///C:\Users\Andy\Documents\Programming\Projects\MovieMediaManager\packages\FSharp.Data.2.0.7\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll' has already loaded from a different location. It cannot be loaded from a new location within the same appdomain.

Comment: It also seems to leak memory somewhat.  VS2013 slows down after a little usage and shows as using 80% memory and needs restarting.  This isn't using interactive.  Just building and running a project using the provider.

Answer (score 2):

I have ran into a couple issues with f# and the FSharp.Data.Dll myself. I had to completely `unisntall` the package from every project in the solution and then reinstall the nuget package. I then had to go to `Tools, Options, F# Tools, type providers` and trust the `FSharp.Data.DLL` for the project you are currently working on. I have also had issues with the DLL being trusted for multiple projects at once and it causes issues as well.

Hope this helps!